# How to remove duplicate from string/mixed list

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a second list without having the 2nd duplicates printed. I figured I could use x.remove(list) but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
x = [] #initiate empty string
    counter = {}

    while list != "DONE":
        list = input() #keep asking for input

        for i in x:
            if not i in counter:
                x.append(list)
            else:
                x.remove(list)
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work you need to be more specific. What were you expecting to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: There are several problems here. Indentation is wrong. You're using `list` as a variable name. You're accessing that before having defined it (which only works because `list` happens to be a built-in name). You're using a dictionary `counter` that always remains empty. And your question is very confusing. What "second list"? What's a "2nd duplicate"? What "doesn't work"?

Comment: Please just explain with example input and output what should happen. Thank you.

Comment: Do you actually want to remove items if the user enters them again? Or just not add them a second time? You can simplify this by making `x` a `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
x = []
while True:
    data = input()
    if data.lower() == "done":
        break
    if data not in x:
        x.append(data)
```

Note the use of `while True` and `break` to avoid having two `input` calls.

Alternatively, use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
x = set()
while True:
    data = input()
    if data.lower() == "done":
        break
    x.add(data)
x = list(x)
```

This will quietly ignore attempts to add duplicates.

If you actually *do* want to allow the user to remove items from `x` by entering them a second time, you can add the `else` and use `remove` (for the list) or `discard` (for the set), e.g.:

```
x = set() # or []
while True:
    data = input()
    if data.lower() == "done":
        break
    if data in x:
        x.discard(data) # or .remove(data)
    else:
        x.add(data) # or .append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates in a list you can just use:

```
In [38]: l1 = [1,2,1,2,1,2]

In [39]: l2= list(set(l1))

In [40]: l2
Out[40]: [1, 2]
```